# Translating LINQ where statements into SSRS filters

Tags: vb.net, linq, reporting-services, filter

I have a linq query that I am trying to rebuild in an SSRS report. I need to apply filters to the dataset but can't seem to wrap my head around exactly how to do it. The way that linq filters the data makes so much sense to me and I can't figure out how to translate it over into filters.

I have set filters for three different rows BLOCKED, CUSTFILE, and UserType

I receive the following values from my server code all as Parameters when I call the report programmatically: Session("UserType"), Profile.PflCUSTFILEID, Profile.pflUSERID

```
If Session("UserType") = 100 Then ' RCUSER ADMIN
    users = users.Where(Function(c) c.BLOCKED = 0)
ElseIf Session("UserType") = 80 Then ' CUSTFILE ADMIN
    users = users.Where(Function(c) c.BLOCKED = 0 And c.CUSTFILE = Profile.pflCUSTFILEID And c.UserType <= 80)
Else ' INDIVIDUAL
    ' FUTURE: Draw users based on themselves or those reporting to them, and those reporting to those people.
    users = users.Where(Function(c) c.USERS = Profile.pflUSERID)
End If
```

Comment: You would probably best be served to look up adding 'Code' to an SSRS report: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-code-to-a-report-ssrs.   Else if you can get out the logic that linq is doing in it's 'Session' you could do a dataset that is used to get a calculated set for reuse.  I'm Rusty on my SSRS,  but I had done something similar and the code part was the answer for me.  HTH

Answer (score 0):

You need to [use calculated parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574922/calculate-an-ssrs-report-parameter-based-on-another). It's been a while since I last did SSRS, but basically there are two types of parameters, user and calculated. Forget about user session, it's not available in SSRS scope. You need to ask user for something. You may be able to [get necessary information via SQL query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-user-transact-sql).

Then you need to construct a query in a way that it always accepts a parameter, you don't modify the actual query. Use a combination of ISNULL, COALESCE etc., and a field name as a backup. So it boils down to `field_name = field_name`, which means the field will not be part of the filter. If there is a performance concern, you can use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` on the query, but make sure it's justified. ISNULL and similar don't work well with DB indices.

Comment: I am programatically calling a report and feeding in those variables from the Session of my program. I'm using Session to basically to check the user's privileges and what they're allowed to see. I can send session as a parameter when I call the report. But I will look further into calculated parameters

Comment: @SentOnLine: If you are programmatically calling the report, you should be able to use regular parameters, and just supply them via your program.

Comment: that is exactly what I am doing. It's just that in Linq it's very easy to say

  " users = users.Where(Function(c) c.BLOCKED = 0 And c.CUSTFILE = Profile.pflCUSTFILEID And c.UserType <= 80) "    

In Ssrs I can only filter on one row at a time

Comment: @SentOnLine: You should try to filter data at the main query level, for performance reasons. Filtering after you got the data will put unnecessary burden on the DB server. Use a static query and calculated parameters to your advantage. If absolutely necessary, I guess you could encapsulate query building in a stored procedure and call that, but this should be your last resort - very difficult to maintain.